# Can I deploy a Jodd framework app to Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-deployment, jodd

Simple question that I haven't seen a simple answer to.

Can I deploy a web application written using [Jodd](http://jodd.org) to Google App Engine? If so, can someone please direct me to an example and/or gotchas?

Thanks,

Shane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Jodd with GAE :) There are some util classes that can not be used (due to GAE restrictions), but only few of them and they are in separated classes, so you will not even notice. Besides that, most of the Jodd things works just fine.

Here is a repo with simple working example of using Jodd Madvoc on GAE:

https://github.com/oblac/jodd-quickstart/tree/master/gapps

You can [see this example live, as well](http://jodd-ngn.appspot.com/index.html).

Please look the sources - there are some important comments and notes regarding the configuration of Madvoc. Not many, just few things that will help, especially with running your web app *locally*, what is important for the development.